# Displaying a .doc file with custom margins

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, margin, doc

This piece of code dispalys a document in a scrollable UIWebView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];   
   _myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 760)];   
   NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pathToDoc/myDoc.doc"];  
   NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
   [_myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];    
   [self.view addSubview:_myWebView]; 

}
```

This works fine except when trying to display a landscape document which has been created with custom margins which are smaller than standard.

The result is the contents of the right-hand edge of the document are chopped off.

Is there any way to display the whole document?

Comment: So what, you are using webview to read a .dov and the .doc has margins larger then normal? So the .doc get's cut off?

Comment: @Steven: yes. The margins are actually smaller than normal, meaning the content area of the document is larger than normal. The far right edge of the content gets lopped off.

Comment: May I ask why you are using webview to read a .doc? Have you tried `_myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;` ?

Comment: @Steven: 1) because I'm new to this and it's the only way I know. Any other suggestions are most welcome. 2) Yes, I tried that and it had no effect.

Comment: @Steven: After a good few days of frustration, I'm still no further forward. Apple dox suggest using UIWebView:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1630.html
I still know of no other way but your comment suggests you do.
Care to share? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after several months of frustration with this (can barely believe how long it took!), it turned out to need only a single line of code to solve the problem.

```
_documentWebView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Add that just after the last line and suddenly all is well in the world.